# invalid command \ir in centOs 6.9 while creating postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, shell, centos, runtime-error

While running by script to create db in postgres, i am getting below error:

OS: CentOs

```
invalid command \ir
```

code throwing this error:

```
\ir ./env_sql_variables.sql
\ir ./${scriptFile}
```

Not sure if this is CentOs 6.9 issue or something else. Any workaround?

Comment: Script ... by whom? From where? On what Pg version? My psychic powers aren't working so well right now. P.s. Please format the question in future, see the help.

Answer (score 1):

At a wild guess given the *total* lack of information provided: whatever script this is was written for some newer PostgreSQL than yours, and your `psql` version doesn't have `\ir` (include-relative).

Comment: PSQL version: psql (8.4.20) . I am guessing psql version is not supporting \ir. Is there any way to do so or any addons which can make it work?